# remove all listeners while performing some actions

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I have a button (named button1) with an OnClickListener and after button is clicked, a task should be execute, and button should become unclickable until task is finished. This is my code:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    removeListeners();
    executeMyTask();
    addListeners();
}

private void disableListeners() {
    button1.setOnTouchListener(null);
    button2.setOnClickListener(null);
}

private void enableListeners() {
    button1.setOnTouchListener(this);
    button2.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

Now it happen that, if I click button while executeMyTask is running (so when listener is disabled), when task finish, onClick is called again.
I would that all clicks performed while executeMyTask is running will be ignored.
how can I do ?

Comment: What is executeMyTask() doing ?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just disable the whole button with:

```
button1.setEnabled(false);
button2.setEnabled(false);
```

And later just re-enable them:

```
button1.setEnabled(true);
button2.setEnabled(true);
```

It will be easier for the users to understand that the button is un-clickable at the moment.

Comment: i obtain the same behavior. if i tap button while is disabled, when button is enabled again, executeMyTask will runn again

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways:

**1)** With disable all other buttons,

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    setButtonEnabled(false);
    executeMyTask();
    setButtonEnabled(true);
}


private void setButtonEnabled(boolean enable) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    btn_1.setEnabled(enable);
    btn_2.setEnabled(enable);
    btn_3.setEnabled(enable);
}
```

**2)** Use a boolean to keep record of async task running or not:

Like:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    removeListeners();
    executeMyTask();
    addListeners();
}

// And in executeMyTask
onPreExecute(){
    ....
    ..
    isAsyncRunning = true;
    ..
    ....
}
onPostExecute(){
    ....
    ..
    isAsyncRunning = false;
    ..
    ....
}    
//And in Button Click Listeners
{
    if(!isAsyncRunning){
        // Do something...        
    }
}
```